# Flutter navigator.push, set it to only push once, disallow user to press multiple times to push multiple pages

Tags: flutter, firebase, push, uilocalnotification, navigator

My app receives in-app notifications from Firebase. When the notification is pressed, it will prompt the user to the page.

My issue is if the notification is pressed multiple times, it will push the same page multiple times, causing to have lots of the pages in the stack. Is it possible to configure and limit `Navigator.push` to push only once?

I have tried using `pushReplacemement` but I'm still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

`PushReplacement` will not work since it always create new instances of widget every time.

I can see 2 ways to fix it:

1. Manage while pushing: You can try to store a variable (or as persistent data) that stores if the page has been pushed or not and only push if it is the first time.
2. Manage while poping: If the number of pages doesn't matter and all you care about is going back to the main screen on pressing back, use the `popUntil` method to pop until to return to the desired page.

Although I do not know the context of your application, getting same notification multiple time is probably not a good idea. You should probably change the functionality there instead. (Just a suggestion and do your own research).

Comment: thanks for your answer first of all, 2nd option was manageable, however for the 1st option, storing in a variable of type boolean u meant? and how do u check that it has been pushed before?